# Let $z$ be a complex number. The number $1$ is written on a board. You perform a series of moves. When can you make terms tend to $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

Let $z$ be a complex number. The number $1$ is written on a board. You perform a series of moves, where in each move you may either

- replace the number $w$ written on the board with $zw$,
  or
- replace the number $w$ with a different complex number $w'$ so that

  $$\max(\lvert\operatorname{Re} w\rvert, \lvert\operatorname{Im} w\rvert) = \max(\lvert\operatorname{Re} w'\rvert, \lvert\operatorname{Im} w'\rvert).$$

After some time, a positive real number less than $0.001$ is written on the board. The set of all $z$ for which this is possible forms a region $A$ in the complex plane. What is the area of $A$?

So I'm baffled on where to begin this problem. I suppose defining $z$ = a + bi. I do not know where to go from here.

I understand the max notation and the $\rm{Re}$ (Real) and $\rm{Im}$ (Imaginary) notation.

This problem was sent to me by my math coach, so this may be from a book.

Comment: It may help to consider the cases $|z|\geq 1$ and $|z|<1$.

Comment: And what is the smallest value of $|w'|$ when $w = z$

Comment: Adding onto Doug, by smallest we only care about smallest in magnitude, since once we have a small enough magnitude we'll have a small enough real/imaginary component and can easily transform it into a real number in one step

Comment: Nice problem, but definitely not a one liner. The domain seems to have a fractal-like structure [see image](https://ibb.co/93y0ND0)

Comment: I'm going to bounty this.

Comment: Seems that one gets the box $\max(|\text{Re}(z)|, |\text{Im}(z)|)< 1$ in the helpful picture of @DinosaurEgg by multiplying by $z$, dropping the smaller real or imaginary part, then repeating. The additional area seems to come from strategically adjusting the point first, then applying $\cdot z$. Problem is an interesting mix of quantities best suited for polar (multiplication by $z$) and rectangular coordinates (max of real/imaginary parts).

Comment: Turns out the region is a 4-leafed clover with area $2+ \pi$; writing a solution now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The region $A$ looks like a 4-leaf clover, and has area $$2 + \pi = 8\int_0^{\pi/4} \cos^2(\pi/4 - \theta) d\theta.$$ A picture of the region is at the bottom of the answer. A nice idea pointed out in a comment below is that one can also compute the area without an integral by dissecting the region into a square of side length $\sqrt{2}$ and two circles of
radius $r = 1/\sqrt{2}$.

Here's an outline of how to determine the region $A$. Polar coordinates are well-suited for getting our hands on the complex multiplication option in the game, and we work mostly in them. Writing every detail would be rather lengthy — I'm happy to explain any of the steps that are unclear.

- $z$ is in $A$ if and only if there is a point $w$ on the boundary of the unit square so $\max(|\rm{Re}(wz)|, |\rm{Im}(wz)|) < 1.$ To see why this suffices, adjust $1$ to $w$ with move 2, apply move $1$, and adjust back to a positive real number $c < 1$. Repeating $n$ times yields the real number $c^n \to 0$.
- Now try to find all $z$ in the region of the form $re^{i\theta}$ for a fixed $\theta$, using the condition above.
- We may as well work with $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$ and $w$ with $\rm{Re}(w) = 1, |\rm{Im}(w)| \leq 1$. (That is $w$ along the right side of the unit square). The rest follows by symmetry, as $\max(|\rm{Re}(\zeta)|, |\rm{Im}(\zeta)|)$ is invariant under conjugation of $\zeta$ and multiplication by $i$.
- The relevant side of the square is parametrized as $\sec(\nu) e^{i\nu}$ for $-\pi/4 \leq \nu \leq \pi/4$, so that the relevant points $zw$ are given by $$r \sec(\nu)e^{i(\theta+\nu)} = r\sec(\nu) \cos(\theta+\nu) + ir\sec(\nu) \sin(\theta + \nu).$$
- Analysis of critical points (where derivatives of either are $0$, or the two are equal, or endpoints) of $\max(|\rm{Re}(r \sec(\nu)e^{i(\theta+\nu)})|, |\rm{Im}(r \sec(\nu)e^{i(\theta+\nu)})|)$ shows that the minimum occurs at $\nu = \pi/4 - \theta$. There, we have $e^{i\pi/4} = \cos(\pi/4) + i \sin(\pi/4) = 1/\sqrt{2}+i/\sqrt{2}$ so $$ \max(|\rm{Re}(r \sec(\pi/4 - \theta)e^{i\pi/4})|, |\rm{Im}(r \sec(\pi/4 - \theta)e^{i\pi/4})|) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}r \sec(\pi/4 -\theta) .$$
- So $re^{i\theta}$ is in the region if and only if $\sqrt{2}\cos(\pi/4 - \theta) > r$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$. Symmetry considerations above together with this yield the polar integral for area above.

The region is bounded by the below curve, plotted in Desmos.
[image: the region looks like a 4-leaf clover]

Comment: I understand the part of  $\max(|\rm{Re}(wz)|, |\rm{Im}(wz)|) < 1.$ because if $wz$ was greater than 1, then we can do move 2 and then move 1, and the number would get bigger.

Comment: Is there a reason to use the exponential form instead of $r$ ($cos$ θ + $i$ $sin$ θ)? . Why did we 45 degrees (/4) instead of something like /2? Or would both work? I have no familiarity with , so I don't understand why it is used here. How did you find the parametrization, and why did we do $e^{i(\theta+\nu)}$?

Comment: And how did you figure out $$\max(|\rm{Re}(r \sec(\pi/4 - \theta)e^{i\pi/4})|, |\rm{Im}(r \sec(\pi/4 - \theta)e^{i\pi/4})|) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}r \sec(\pi/4 -\theta).$$

Comment: Can you explain how on your first bullet point the moveset described is necessary? You have only justified the sufficient, but I do not see why it's necessary.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg The unit square is exactly the collection of points that move 1 can adjust the starting point $1$ to. The condition says that there is a point that move 1 adjusts to that move $2$ improves (decreases the max of). Any move 2 application that would improve something with max strictly greater than $1$ would improve the same thing scaled down to size $1$. So there are no strategies for improvement that cannot be used immediately, and the condition is necessary.

Comment: @Knocker379 Writing this point as $e^{i\theta}$ has nicer multiplication identities: $(r_1e^{i\theta})(r_2e^{i\theta_2}) = r_1 r_2 e^{i (\theta_1 + \theta_2)}$, which make the computation easier. It could be done without this. Choosing $\pi/4$ is a normalization that simplifies the computation -- the interval $\theta \in [-\pi/4, \pi/4]$ corresponds to exactly one side of the triangle and reduces the work in the most technical step (critical point analysis). The character $\zeta$ was just chosen to clarify that I'm talking about the max function in general and not for something already fixed.

Comment: I'm not seeing how you got to secant(v) though

Comment: Oh, $r = \sec(\theta)$ for $\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ is the polar parameterization of the vertical line $x = 1$. The range of $\theta$ parameterizing the side of the square we're interested in is $-\pi/4 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$. One can see this by drawing a triangle.

Comment: @AlexNolte: I haven't checked your analysis. However, your final boundary $r=\sqrt{2}\cos(\pi/4-\theta)$ is actually what it appears to be: in the first quadrant, it's an arc of a circle with diametric endpoints $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ (ie, center $(1/2,1/2)$ and radius $1/\sqrt{2}$). Knowing this, the area is trivial to compute: dissect the region appropriately into pieces that form two complete circles (each of area $\pi/2$) and two unit squares. No integration required.

Comment: Could you explain how you did the analysis of critical points (5th bullet point)?

Comment: And how did you get $$ \max(|\rm{Re}(r \sec(\pi/4 - \theta)e^{i\pi/4})|, |\rm{Im}(r \sec(\pi/4 - \theta)e^{i\pi/4})|) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}r \sec(\pi/4 -\theta) .$$*

Comment: @Knocker379 After the first comment about the second point, I added a sentence to the explanation above immediately before the equality which I hope clarifies it. For the critical point analysis: this is the sort of thing best understood by doing the computation out oneself. Here's how it goes. Take the derivatives of both real and imaginary parts and set to $0$. One can reason that neither derivative ever vanishes on the relevant side of the square. So the only critical point possibilities are endpoints and where the min and max are equal. Where they are equal ends up being the minimum.

Comment: @Blue That's a very nice observation, thanks! I like this approach to finding the area, and eliminating the need for an integral, and edited the answer to mention it.

Comment: I awarded the bounty. Thank you for answering all my questions and for your great work.

Comment: Thanks! I found it a fun problem. Take care!